# Mapping database entities to domain entities via repositories - static property or separate service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, domain-driven-design

I am working on an application where my database schema does not match up well to my domain model, and modifications to the database schema are not under my control.  Because of this, I end up doing a lot of mapping in my repository calls, and I have many concrete repos to handle the mapping to and from the database (using entity framework database-first).  What I am looking for is an elegant way to make calls to my repositories based on the domain entity object type.  Thus far, the domain model itself is still very anemic, as we are still in the process of defining business rules.

I have seen an example elsewhere (can't recall the link) where the repository calls were passed through the domain entities via a static property, but I do not know if this will present threading issues or whether it violates any domain model principles, especially if we decide to implement DI/IoC down the road.

Here is an example of what I have so far. For the sake of brevity, I have simplified the mapping calls to the database, as the mapping in the actual application is more complex.

**Repository example:**

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(int id);
    void Save(T entity);
}

public abstract class RepositoryFactory<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected MyDbContext db;
    protected int userId;

    protected RepositoryFactory()
    {
        this.db = new MyDbContext();
        this.userId = WebSecurity.GetCurrentUser().UserId;
    }

    public abstract T GetById(int id);
    public abstract void Save(T entity);
}

public class CustomerRepository : RepositoryFactory<Customer>
{
    public override void Save(Customer customer)
    {
        var entity = db.customers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.customerid == customer.Id && p.users.userid == userId);

        if (entity == null) return;  // TODO: Add error trapping

        // Mapping (lots of reshaping happening here)
        entity.customername = customer.Name;
        entity.customeraddress = customer.Address;
        // ...

        // Save changes to DB
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override Customer GetById(int id)
    {
        var entity = db.customers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.customerid == id && p.users.userid == userId);
        if (entity == null) return null;  // TODO: Add error trapping
        return new Customer
        {
            Name = entity.customername,
            Address = entity.customeraddress,
            // ...
        };
    }
}
```

**Domain Entity example:**

```
public class Entity { public int Id { get; set; } }

public class Customer : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    // Does this violate any domain principles?
    public static IRepository<Customer> Repository
    {
        get { return new CustomerRepository(); }
    }
}
```

With this code, from my controller I can do something like:

```
Customer customer = Customer.Repository.GetById(id);
```

Instead of:

```
IRepository<Customer> repo = new CustomerRepository();
Customer customer = repo.GetById(id);
```

This seems like a very elegant solution to my problem, and it also keeps me from needing to include the Repository namespace in my controllers (MVC).  If this smells funny and there is a better way to handle this, I'd love to learn.  The only other thing I can think of is creating a separate crud service to handle my repository calls, but I imagine for that I would need a dictionary or hash table to map my concrete repos to my domain model objects, and that seems like it would be a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an inversion of control (dependency injection) container and injecting your repositories into your controllers or wherever. This way you can use them like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;

    public HomeController(IRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var customer = _customerRepository.GetById(id)

        return View(customer);
    }
}
```

This way, if you ever need to replace CustomerRepository class, or need to have multiple versions (say CustomerRepositoryEntityFramework or CustomerRepositoryNHibernate) you can simply replace a new class inheriting from IRepository and your controller code will still continue to work with no change.

I recommend using Castle Windsor, or Ninject, or one of the many other IoC containers.

Also, you generally want to keep your domain entities as poco's (Plain Old CLR Object). This means separating everything out of your entities including validation, business rules, etc. and simply having only its properties. This allows you to pass your domain entities through the pipeline more easily, specially since you are in the early stages of development. This will offer you the most flexibility in the future.

Comment: So if validation and business rules are not part of the domain entities, and we are including repositories directly in the controllers, how does business logic get applied in this scenario?  I am utilizing ViewModels for basic form field validation, but obviously we do not want to add more complex business logic to the ViewModels.

Comment: By including the repositories directly in the controller you are limiting yourself to where you have your business logic. Remember the whole idea here is separation of concerns. Your ViewModels should not have any business logic, you simply want to use these to pass data between your view and controller. Have you looked into implementing a service pattern for your business layer? and injecting your repositories to your services? and in turn, injecting your services into your controllers?

Comment: Take a look at this project: http://ddmvc4.codeplex.com/ or this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle they both have good design patterns and may help.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into FluentValidation as it allows you to completely separate validation and have multiple layers of validation.

Comment: Those links are exactly what I was looking for.  The services pattern seems to be the big missing link and where I am struggling to grasp.  I am already using FluentValidation but I think I need to revisit my implementation after reviewing these two projects.  Thank you!